# My Columns in Dataframe has change the location after I use the method

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Why does my Dataframe at "SummerBronze" and "WinterBronze" has change the location after I use stack()?

[image: Picture]

And this is my previous code
[image]

Comment: I looked at the pandas.DataFrame.stack documentation and I did not see any thing regarding the order of the columns after the stack call.  I think the columns are sorted by their name after the stack call.

Comment: @theDBA My other dataframe try stack() too but it doesn't sorted like this so I don't know how to fix it